# Error while Scala install on Eclipse Juno

Tags: eclipse, scala, eclipse-juno

I am trying to install Scala on Eclipse Juno Release 1, through Update Site - Scala - http://download.scala-ide.org/nightly-update-juno-master-2.10.x

But this throws an error -

```
> Cannot complete the install because one or more required items could
> not be found.   Software being installed: Scala IDE for Eclipse
> 2.1.0.nightly-2_10-201210081405-e0d2b95 (org.scala-ide.sdt.feature.feature.group
> 2.1.0.nightly-2_10-201210081405-e0d2b95)   Missing requirement: Scala IDE for Eclipse 2.1.0.nightly-2_10-201210081405-e0d2b95
> (org.scala-ide.sdt.feature.feature.group
> 2.1.0.nightly-2_10-201210081405-e0d2b95) requires 'org.eclipse.sdk 0.0.0' but it could not be found
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

juno (eclipse 4.2) is not fully supported yet.
from the [FAQ](http://scala-ide.org/docs/user/faq.html): *"The Scala IDE 2.0 officially supports both Eclipse 3.6 (Helium) and Eclipse 3.7 (Indigo)."*
as the ScalaIDE site says: you can *"walk on the wild side"* and use [Scala IDE 2.1.0 Milestone 2 for Eclipse 4.2 (Juno)](http://scala-ide.org/download/milestone.html).
anyway, i recommend you use the bundled version made by typesafe: [**get it here**](http://typesafe.com/stack/scala_ide_download)
IMHO, it is way better than IDEA (used both), and moreover, *juno* has some efficiency issues. for now, i suggest you stick to *indigo*...